# Taking a picture and storing in coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

In one view controller, I take a picture and store in coredata:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    if image == nil{
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    imageView.image = image
    let newImageDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Image", inManagedObjectContext: context!) 
    let newImage = Image(entity: newImageDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newImage.image = imageView
    var error = NSError?()
    context?.save(&error)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

In another, I display the images in a collection view:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    let store = stores[indexPath.row]

    var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UIImageView //ERROR HAPPENS HERE

    imageView.image = UIImage(data: store.image as NSData)
```

But then I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I know that it saves because when I take a picture and print stores.count, I get the number of pictures i took. So I want to display the images I have saved onto a collection view of UIImages. What am I doing wrong?